# The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, export-to-excel

I am trying to downlaod an excel sheet and I am dynamically generating its filename which has to be in the following format:

eg:

```
User_Wise_List_Of_Documents_2013_On_16_04_2013
```

For this I wrote the following code:

> string currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
>
> string currentYear=DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
>
> filename = Server.MapPath("~/User/Documents/") +
>   "User_Wise_List_Of_Documents_" + currentYear  + "*on*" + currentDate +
>   ".xls";

Somehow, its giving me the following exception:

> `The given path's format is not supported.`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your filename contains invalid chars like `:` Because you are forming filename with `string currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()`.

See the list for invalid chars

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
```

**EDIT**

You can use this to replace invalid chars

```
string newdatestr = String.Join("",currentDate.Select(c => invalidChars.Contains(c) ? '_' : c));
```

Comment: @ankitaalung Just replace invalid chars with another valid char like `_`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Didnt work for me :( Is that code below fine?

string currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
                string currentYear=DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                filename = Server.MapPath("~/User/Documents/") + "User_Wise_List_Of_Documents_" + currentYear  + "_on_" + currentDate + ".xls";
                var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
                string newdatestr = String.Join("", currentDate.Select(c => invalidChars.Contains(c) ? '_' : c));

Comment: @ankitaalung I doesn't work because you replace invalid characters **after** you have formed your filename. use `newdatestr` instead of `currentDate` while creating the `filename`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the result of `Server.MapPath("~/User/Documents/")`?

It will return the directory path of your website's folder `"/User/Documents/"`, which would be for example `"C:\wwwroot\User\Documents\"`. You cant download a file from there (unless you're hosting local, in which case it might work, but for you only.

Probably you're looking for the `Page.ResolveUrl()` function, which will create a web uri relative to your website, rather than to the filesystem.

Comment: Yes Infact I've been saving my files from quite a while there until the time I decided to append current year and date in the filename.

Comment: No. I am not creating it outside my project. Its a folder created by me in the project itself.